# How to paginate a form in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem. Last time, I made a grading system for teachers. I have a form for grading teachers but I am confused on how to paginate that form. If the entries are more than 10 then it causes problems.

```
<form action="n.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<table width="642" height="215" border="10" align="left" cellspacing="0"  >
<tr>
    <th class="style5">Teacher ID</th>
    <th width="90" class="style5">Teacher Name</th>
    <th width="127" class="style5">Teacher Registration</th>
    <th width="135" class="style5">Teacher Qualification</th>
    <th width="92" class="style5">Teacher Subject</th>
    <th width="92" class="style5">Action</th>
</tr>
<?php
include 'conn.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teacher ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $id=$row['tid'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td height="50" align="center" class="style5"><?php echo $row['tid'];?></td>
        <td align="center" class="style5"><?php echo $row['tname'];?></td>
        <td align="center" class="style5"><?php echo $row['treg'];?></td>
        <td align="center" class="style5"><?php echo $row['qualification'];?></td>
        <td align="center" class="style5"><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
         <td align="center"> <input type="text" name="rating[<?php echo $id; ?>]">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }   
}else{
    echo "<center><p><font size=10/> No Records</p></center>";
}

$conn->close();
?><tr><td colspan="6">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"></td></tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: So what is the problem? Do you get an error? You say "if the entries are more than 10 then it causes problems." does this mean you get output on the page? How I see it you need to echo the `<tr>` and `<td>` within the while loop. try it

Comment: i mean it exceeds the page's limit i put that code in one div and the div size is not too much large to have large number of entries

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP you could define a page size:

```
$page_size = 10; // number of teachers per page
```

And start at page 1:

```
$page = 1;
```

You change your SQL to use these values:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM teacher LIMIT " . $page_size * ($page - 1) . ", " . $page_size;
```

Now you'll only be shown 10 teachers from page 1.

You can change your script so that the page is read from the URL `/yourscript.php?page=2`:

```
$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1; // take from query string or default to 1
```

Next step is to insert *next* and *prev* link in your html:

```
<?php 
$next = $page + 1;
$prev = $page - 1 > 0 ? $page - 1 : 1;
echo "<a href='?page=$prev'>prev page</a>";
echo "<a href='?page=$next'>next page</a>";
```

You can improve your scripts by checking how many pages there is using a count of teacher records

```
$pages = ceil(count($teachers) / $page_size);
```

I think you can take it from here.

**UPDATE**: I've merged my suggestions with your code:

```
<form action="n.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table width="642" height="215" border="10" align="left" cellspacing="0">

       ... your table stuff ...
<?php
include 'conn.php';

$page_size = 10;

// Get total pages
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM teacher";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$teacher_count = $result[0]["cnt"]; // I'm unsure how you DB class works;
$pages = ceil($teachers / $page_size);

$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1; // take from query string or default to 1
$next = $page + 1 > $pages ? $pages : $page + 1;
$prev = $page - 1 > 0 ? $page - 1 : 1;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM teacher LIMIT " . $page_size * ($page - 1) . ", " . $page_size;
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
    $id=$row['tid'];
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td height="50" align="center" class="style5"><?php echo $row['tid'];?></td>
        <td align="center" class="style5"><?php echo $row['tname'];?></td>
        <td align="center" class="style5"><?php echo $row['treg'];?></td>
        <td align="center" class="style5"><?php echo $row['qualification'];?></td>
        <td align="center" class="style5"><?php echo $row['subject'];?></td>
         <td align="center"> <input type="text" name="rating[<?php echo $id; ?>]">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }   
}else{
    echo "<center><p><font size=10/> No Records</p></center>";
}

$conn->close();
?><tr><td colspan="6">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Enter"></td></tr>
</table>
<?php
if ($next > 1) {
    echo "<a href='?page=$prev'>prev page</a>";
}
if ($prev > 0 && $page !== 1) {
    echo "<a href='?page=$next'>next page</a>";
}
?>
</form>
```

Comment: `$page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;`

Comment: @michael i want to do paging inside a form but it is not working properly.i want to do paging for thr teacher's table data only but the "enter" button does not work after that

Comment: @EashaKhan, I'm not sure what you mean by inside the form?

Comment: I can update my answer with your example and then we can go from there

Comment: look my answer dear sir

Comment: It seems like you are on your way to the answer. My code was just meant as an explanation of the concepts.

Comment: sir the grades are not submitted after paging

Comment: sir this line is shown some error $teacher_count = $result[0]["cnt"];

Comment: @EashaKhan yes like I wrote I don't know how your DB class works? How do you get out a single value?

Comment: @EashaKhan you might have finished your project completely, but if your question was answered please accept the answer (click the check-mark left of the question)

Comment: @EashaKhan please accept the answer if it helped you along the way as you described in your question.