# Which page to use when building the url on a php pagination function?

Tags: php, pagination

I have an `index.php` page which contains a div which will later on become the parent of a newly appended table.

```
<div id="container">
//Here a table will be appended later on
</div>
```

That table is created and its contents acquired from a MySQL query stored in another file: `refresh.php` All is done via Ajax GET

```
  $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "refresh.php",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function(data) {
```

The problem is that when I build the pagination function, if I build the url using index.php, so the result is http://host/index.php?page=1 , the pagination doesn´t work (the value $page doesn´t update and it remains in the first page always)

But instead, if I build the url with refresh.php, so it´s http://host/refresh.php?page=1 then it works fine and the pagination goes as expected.

But using refresh.php, although it makes the pagination work, breaks some other things I had (javascript functions, styles...)

Sorry I am not attaching much code here, but my question is more theoretical, and quite simple: **Which one is the page that needs to be used to build pagination urls, the php where the table is shown, or the php where the sql query resides?**

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34941746/how-to-paginate-a-form-in-php/34944807#34944807

Comment: Your PHP with SQL and HTML can be the same. The PHP with the SQL should make the $page variable available to the PHP that renders the HTML.